# Highstock Navigator and xAxis show numbers instead of dates

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Data loaded from local csv file. Webpage run on local Node 'Connect' and 'serveStatic' webserver.

Navigator and the xAxis shows numbers instead of dates stored in the csv file, hence rangeselector and zoom doesn't work.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:80%; height:600px;"></div>  
</body>
<script>
    $(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Kilogram'
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            xAxis: {
                isInternal: true
        },
            yAxis: {
                isInternal: true
        }
        },
        data: {
            csvURL: window.location.origin + '/trend.csv'
        }
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

The 'isInternal' parameters are set to workaround [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8196) issue.

When I select 'View data table' in the menu the following is displayed:

```
Date    Value
09-06-2018 18:00:15 1296.26098632813
09-06-2018 18:28:09 1451.98901367188
2   563.752014160156
3   429.237213134766
4   445.504516601563
5   1216.92199707031
...
```

There is something odd going on with the dates. It looks like only the first two rows are processed correctly.

Can anyone please take a look, and maybe point me in the right direction?

Sample from csv file:

```
DateTime;Value
09/06/2018 18:00:15;1296.26098632813
09/06/2018 18:28:09;1451.98901367188
09/06/2018 18:56:03;563.752014160156
09/06/2018 19:23:57;429.237213134766
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how your csv file is formatted. A small sample of the CSV would be really helpful. As it is, the only thing I can suggest is to make sure dates are in milliseconds since 1970, as that is the *only* format highcharts accepts.

Comment: @ewolden Sample from csv file added.

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/Lwbpcux1/9/. So I am unsure what it could be. I would try to insert a larger portion of your CSV data into that jsfiddle and see if it works there.

Comment: Thank you, @ewolden. I inserted the complete content of the csv file into the fiddle, and the issue came back.

Comment: Fiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/theSwan/frjp96w8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your dates being formatted dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM:SS, when javascript expects mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM:SS. If there are just dates, then this can be handled with [**`dateFormat`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/data.dateFormat). However, since there is also time involved, it fails. To take care of that we can parse dates manually, like this:

```
function parseEUdate(d) {
  return (new Date(
    d.substring(6,10),    //Year
    d.substring(3,5) - 1, //Month
    d.substring(0,2),     //Day
    d.substring(11,13),   //Hour
    d.substring(14,16),   //Minute
    d.substring(17,19)    //Second
    )).getTime()
}
```

This is then used in highcharts like this:

```
data: {
  parseDate: function(d) {
    return parseEUdate(d)
  },
  ...
}
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/frjp96w8/75/

**API on parseDate:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/data.parseDate

**`Date()` documentation:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Much appreciated, @ewolden ! I thought the date formatting was covered by this: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/data.dateFormat. (Valid options include: dd/mm/YYYY). One thing, though: The chart seems to be 'off' by one month, charting starts at 9th July instead of 9th June?

Comment: I also thought dateFormat could handle that, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle the time. Ohh right, months in `Date()` is 0 indexed, updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time on this. Working as required now. Thanks again.